# How to keep showing virtual keyboard on Android after a message is sent in web chat bot?

Tags: javascript, direct-line-botframework, virtual-keyboard, web-chat

We have a chatbot using the bot framework. The front end connects to it via direct line using The Bot Framework Web Chat component (https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat).

We use this chatbot on our website that also serves mobile users (Android / iOS) that use a virtual keyboard. So far we have only been able to test our code on Android.

When a user taps the chatbots textbox the virtual keyboard shows up. The user types a message and presses the enter key on the keyboard. The message is sent and the keyboard is still visible for the user to send another message. All good so far.

But if the user sends the message using the button instead of the enter key the virtual keyboard disappears.

[image: Enter key with orange arrow, and send button with red arrow]

This means that users that prefer the send button over the enter key have to click the textbox to re-open the keyboard every time they send a message. This behavior is simply annoying and we do not want to annoy our users. So I have been tasked to fix this.

I have tried to show the keyboard using the following this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("webchat__icon-button");
for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", focusChatbotInput);
}                

function focusChatbotInput() {
  let textbox = document.getElementsByClassName("webchat__send-box-text-box__input")[0];
  if (textbox) {
    textbox.focus();
  }
}
```

I also tried calling `focusChatbotInput` from the click event of the entire webchat div. This does open the keyboard when the user clicks anywhere in the div except on the send button.

I also tried making my own custom send button that calls

```
<button onclick="focusChatbotInput(); document.getElementsByClassName("webchat__icon-button")[1].click();">Send</button>
```

This did not work.

It seems that something within the library in the send buttons click event handler breaks focusing on the textbox.

Does anybody have an idea of how to work around this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try working within Web Chat vs. beside it. What I mean is, try applying some of the above methods as a response to every activity that comes thru Web Chat's store. So, when `action.type === DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY` is true, the click event is called. I've done similar to this in the past, though, admittedly, not within Android.

Comment: Another consideration is to focus not ONLY on the button but also the encompassing div. In a previous test in swapping out the send button, I could easily do it but it wouldn't respond to a click until I included the surrounding element. Be aware, I last did this a couple+ versions ago, so functionality/classes may be different in Web Chat, now.

Comment: Hey @StevenKanberg thanks for responding. Our Product Owner has decided that 'hiding the keyboard this way is a nice feature so users can read the incoming messages'. So I guess I don't need an answer to this anymore. It may still be useful for others.